# Ubuntu 14.04 wifi keeps disconnecting

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I had a buf in Ubuntu 12.04 where it kept disconnecting me from vertain Wifi routers
What helped were these 4 commands:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo rmmod -f iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

But now i updated to 14.04 and when i use sudo rmmod -f iwlwifi it returns this error:

```
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:769 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'iwlwifi': Resource temporarily unavailable
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module iwlwifi: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

This information may be needed, my wireless card should be:

```
description: Wireless interface
product: Centrino Wireless-N 2200
vendor: Intel Corporation
```

I will provide any additional information if you can help me solve this problem, thank you

Comment: Instead of removing and loading modules. Create `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` with the content: `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` then reboot (you may need to run `# update-initramfs -u`)

Comment: You made me realize i had some older stuff in /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
I commented all previous lines, added yours and everything works fine now
I owe you a beer/cola (anything you choose :) )
Thank you kindly

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of removing and loading modules. Create
>   /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf with the content: options iwlwifi
>   11n_disable=1 then reboot (you may need to run # update-initramfs -u)

This solution by user "Arch user" worked
I didnt need to run update-initramfs -u